# Button to go back to the previous page

Tags: android, button, back

I want to make a button that allow user to go back to the previous page when click. Just work like the physical back button on the android device. What should I add to the java file?

here is the code(xml):

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button00"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/st_pp"
        android:textColor="#01646d"
        android:background="#fef200"/>
```

here is the code(java):

```
bn00.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent it1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                startActivity(it1);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Just use finish(); in onclick.

Comment: I put the method "cancelAction" in the onClick, then in my class I wrote `public void cancelAction(View v){ finish(); } ` ... works great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To go back to previous activity use `finish()` method. But note that previous activity not contains `finish()` while you call current activity.

Code :

```
bn00.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                finish();
            }

        });
```

Using above code you can go to your previous activity. You can also call `finish()` in `onKeyDown()` method like..

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
       finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: and I have a little problem that is how to set the translation between pages and pages?

Comment: What you mean by translation ?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use `finish()` on your current `Activity`. It will remove current `Activity` from the stack, display previous one and therefore it will work as back button.

```
bn00.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just call a finish() to the current activity, it should go back to the previous one.

For further info see the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

The `finish();` method will end the current activity and show the previous.

But the `onBackPressed();` method will press the back button. But the default implementation (without an Override) will call the `finish();` method anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
bn00.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Intent it1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                //startActivity(it1);

                finish(); //just add this
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Android has a hardware back button which does the job. So i would recommend against have a button that does the same. When hardware back button is pressed the current activity in the back stack is popped, destroyed and the previous activity in the back stack takes focus.

You call finish() on button click as below

```
  bn00.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
           finish();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "bn00" write "button00" in your code because you have set "button00" as your button id in your xml.
And as said by other's too, call `finish()` inside `onClick()` method. Which will end your current activity and load your previous activity which has not finished yet.

```
buttonn00.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            finish();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, You just need:

```
bn00.setOnClickListener { finish() }
```